# Dynamic PIVOT with varchar columns

Tags: sql-server, dynamic, pivot

I'm trying to to pivot rows into columns. I basically have lots of lines where every N rows means a row on a table I'd like to list as a result set. I'll give a short example:

I have a table structure like this:

[image: Table structure]

Keep it in mind that I removed lots of rows to simplify this example. Every 6 rows means 1 row in the result set, which I would like to be like this:

[image: Desired output]

- All columns are varchar types (that's why I couldn't get it done with pivot)
- Number os columns are dynamic, so it's the number of rows in source table
- Logically, Number of rows (table rows in result set) are equally dynamic

Comment: You have a problem with your design (apart from the fact that you need dynamic SQL). What identifies that the "first" value of `DESCRIPTION` goes with the "first" value `CODE` for instance?, there is no column that helps you to give an order to the rows. You say "every 6 rows means 1 row in the resultset", but we don't have a way to group those 6 rows together, there is no such thing as a "natural order" of a table, we need the actual order

Comment: As I said, I removed rows (and also columns) to simplify my example. My app adds itself the rows into the table based on another column table. So it's guaranteed that I'll have one table row for every N rows in my datatable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually did it.
I wrote a SQL while...do based on the number of columnns registered for the resultset. This way I could write a dynamic SQL clause for N columns based on the values read. In the end I just inserted the resultset in a temp table, and voi lá.

Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 1):

(Not really an answer, but it's what I've got.)

This is a name/value pair table, right? Your query will require something that identifies which "set" of rows is associated with one another. Without something like this, I don't see how the query can be written. The key factor is that you must never assume that data will be returned from SQL (Server, at least) in any particular order. How the data is stored internally generally, but not always, determines how it is returned when order is not specified.

Another consideration: what if (when?) a row is missing -- say, Product 4 has no Price B column? That would break a simple "every six rows" rule. "Start fresh with every new Code row" would it problems if a Code is missed or when (not if) data is not returned in the anticipated order.

If you have some means of grouping items, let us know in an updated question, but otherwise I don't think this one is particularly solvable.

Comment: The common answer to questions like this is "normalize your data", by creating a table with (say) those six columns. Alas, the common reply to such answers is "I can't change the table structure". But, if you need to work a lot with the data in "pivoted" form, you should seriously consider upgarding the table structure.

Comment: As said on my comment above, My app itself adds the rows, so I can trust I'll always have N datatable rows for every row in my result set.